# QGIS File Read Error when opening an existing project

Tags: qgis

My computer will not open a project i have been working on for weeks! it is coming up with an error of

> Project file read error: unexpected end of file at line 1 column 1 for
>   file C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/Nxxxx/Exxxx.qgs

Is there anyway to get it back?

Comment: Was this file made with an earlier version of QGIS? I have had problems opening older files after upgrading Quantum.

Comment: You can also look at the project file, since it is text based (XML).

Comment: How do i look up the project file? It was created on an earlier one but think it crashed when i tried to save.

Comment: Just follow the path mentioned in the error path. The file is a text file, so you can open it with any text editor. I'm using notepad++ for such things. once installed, you can open every file with it by right-clicking in the explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just encountered same problem (error while saving, couldn't reopen project) and mostly resolved it -->
Open your .qgs project file with a text editor (e.g. notepad, notepad++, textedit) and it should show the xml markup.

The 'unexpected end of file' is because the application did not finish saving the end of the document, and so there are xml tags that were not closed.  Add closing tags where needed, for example my file needed:
/maplayer
/projectlayers
properties
/properties
/qgis

It will be easier if you can open a project file that is working with notepad as well to compare the differences.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 20):

I have encountered this error before and it has just occurred again.  QGIS crashed before my project could be saved.  When I attempted to re-open the project I got the same error as above.  The project file was empty (0k).

I found the actual project data was stored in a file (which may be hidden on your system - if so, you need to enable view hidden files) with the same project name, but called `yourfilename.qgs~`.

To recover, I opened the `.qgs~` file in Wordpad and then saved it immediately as the .qgs file, overwriting the empty `.qgs` file.  I closed Wordpad, launched QGIS and reopened the project - no problem.

Using Windows 7 home 64bit and QGIS 2.4.0 64 bit.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time!
Any idea why it happens?

Comment: Me too - great answer.

Comment: Great answer.  Unfortunately this bug has persisted across updates, and even without QGIS crashing.

Comment: No idea why it happens @H.Wiener.

Comment: I have not had this problem for a while @deepwinter.  The only major change I have made was switching to QGIS standalone 32 bit.

Comment: Hi @DavidJamesEtheridge - thank you! You just saved me a serious headache!

Answer (score 2):

Your data is not in the .qgs file, but in shapefiles or spatialite databases you added to the project. So your data is not lost.

You can always create a new project, and add the same layers as before. Only styling may be lost. You can save that too in a file, if it is worth saving.

Comment: I know this. it is just that there is an amount of data that i do not wish to have to rebuild. which is what i ended up doing in the end.

Answer (score 2):

To recover, open both file the '.qgs~' and '.qgs' file in Notepad. Copy the HTML (all text inside the  '.qgs~') file and then paste it into the '.qgs' file, save it. Open your newly saved file using your QGIS desktop. Then your problems will disappear.

Comment: Fyi, it's not HTML, it's XML.

Comment: Renaming the `xyz.qgs~` to `xyz-SAVED.qgs` might be easier. With `Project -> Save As ...` you can then overwrite the broken project file.

Comment: Alternative:I simply deleted the .qgs and changed the file extension for the .qgs~ to .qgs and opened that and it loaded fine. Just saved once it opened

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. thank you for you simple and easy to follow instructions.