# Project file read error: Unexpected end of file at line 9957 column 1

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

On reading the answers from a similar question earlier i still cannot retrieve my project.

I last used this project in June and obviously something went wrong when saving or creating the new layer that i did. I tried to restore is to a previous state and there doesn't appear to be one even after refreshing.

I now try to open the QGIS file and i get ***"project file read error: unexpected end of file at line 9957 column 1 for file"***

---

I ended up creating a new QGIS project and copying the SHP files over, discarding the layer that i played with before!

Comment: qgis project files (at least at earlier versions) are not encrypted. If you have a line editor you could read line 9957 and see what the issue is. perhaps knowing that (and adding it to the question) would provide a direction. But this question is unanswerable otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33426/qgis-file-read-error-when-opening-an-existing-project?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS keeps project file copies with .qgs~ file ending. Check your project folder if there is any such file. You can just rename it to remove the ~ and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In a productive environment, backups are strongly recommended.

You can try to sanitize the file by adding a `</qgis>` tag at the end.

There will be more tags opened, but not closed. A good text editor like notepad++  can help you to discover and close them.