# Project do not open anymore because of a minidump

Tags: qgis

I have closed my project two days ago and this message appeared : minidump déposé dans C:\Users\wwf-adm\AppData\Local\Temp\qgis-20150903-171144-3780-1392-8fdd08a.dmp
When I try to open my project, I have this message : Erreur de lecture du fichier de projet : unexpected end of file à la ligne 1 et colonne 1 pour le fichier D:/French Guiana/Projets SIG/zcb_terre_3.qgs
And when I close the message, there is nothing into my project, completely empty.

I do not know how to continue to work on my project !

Comment: I forgot to give you my version of QGIS : Version de QGIS 2.4.0-Chugiak Révision du code 8fdd08a
Compilé avec Qt 4.8.5 Utilisant Qt 4.8.5
Compilé avec GDAL/OGR 1.11.0                                          Utilisé avec GDAL/OGR 1.11.0
Compilé avec GEOS 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 Utilisé avec GEOS 3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921
Version du client PostgreSQL 9.2.4 Version de SpatiaLite 4.1.1
Version de QWT 5.2.3 Version de PROJ.4 : 480
Version de QScintilla2 2.7.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159240/project-file-read-error-unexpected-end-of-file-at-line-9957-column-1 Anyway, your data files are stored separately, so only the styling is lost. If the styling is complicated, you can save that too.