# Can't open my saved .qgs file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, error, qgs

When I try to open my .qgs file I get the following error:
[image]

It says that the project can't be opened, and that something is wrong when trying to read the project file, this is my translation.

Can I do anything to "fix" the file so I can open it?

No, I have no backup, just a .qgs~, does that help?
I use QGIS 2.12.1 and Windows 10, and the file I'm trying to open is also made in 2.12.1.

Comment: I've had the problem recently and found no other solution than re-creating the project...

Comment: looks like the same message [in this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33426/qgis-file-read-error-when-opening-an-existing-project), you may be able to fix the file as it's xml.

Comment: The answer by David James Etheridge in the linked question saved my day! It worked so I didn't need to redo my project.

Comment: Good job @StevenKay! I didn't know that QGS files were XML...